# Svg map not working if I save it .html

Tags: html, svg

```
  <svg xmlns="http:/www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 462.22 473.42">
 <g
     transform="translate(-140.31946,-267.08233)">
    <clipPath
       id="img">
      <path
         style="fill:#cccccc;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-opacity:1"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         d="m 164.84,522.87 0.11,0.44 1.2,1.23 1.14,0.03 2.18,0.85 1.25,-0.2 1.87,-1.43 0.73,-0.13 1.15,0.06 0.44,0.49 1.07,0.01 0.72,-0.56 1.34,0.46 1.3,1.66 0.43,3.08 1.11,0.53 -0.73,2 0.31,0.44 0.75,-0.43 2.12,0.49 0.38,-0.41 0.08,-1.14 0.5,-0.65 1.15,0.02 0.95,-0.98 1.4,-0.6 0.35,0.14 1.03,-0.31 0.34,1.32 3.17,0.61 0.54,-0.61 1.37,-0.08 0.37,-0.9 1.36,-0.97 0.96,-0.04 1.82,-0.88 1.32,-1.82 1.02,-0.33 0.78,0.08 0.9,0.77 1.68,0.43 1.53,1.59 0.56,0.03 0.44,1.16 0.64,0.05 0.76,1.3 1.11,-0.38 1.98,1.3 1.06,-0.19 1.55,-1.16 1.19,0.19 1.42,1.41 0.07,0.65 -0.46,1.06 -0.88,0.44 -0.59,0.89 0.04,1.45 -0.39,1.05 0.55,0.92 1.27,-0.23 1.82,1.1 0.57,-0.14 0.86,0.29 1.19,-0.73 -0.03,-0.84 -0.59,0.44 -0.61,-0.27 -0.39,-1.27 1.54,0.16 -0.51,-1.37 0.76,-0.87 1.17,-0.57 1.82,0.38 1.75,-0.45 0.85,-0.57 1.24,0.37 1.64,-0.73 1.19,0.33 0.45,1.49 1.63,0.27 1.39,-0.51 1.06,0.18 1.41,-0.41 1.73,-0.02 1.05,-0.56 0,0 0.73,2.16 1.58,0.07 0.44,-0.1 1.09,-1.33 -0.15,-0.73 0.49,-0.29 0.74,0.15 -0.19,2.49 -0.71,0.41 -0.18,0.46 0.06,1.8 -1.56,1.65 0.06,0.37 0.66,0.5 -0.07,0.59 0.49,0.3 0.25,0.62 1.89,1.42 2.04,1.03 1.18,-0.31 0.43,0.37 1.39,-0.26 0.4,0.22 0.91,1.85 -0.28,1.03 0.23,0.58 1.65,1.36 1.06,0.05 0.7,0.38 0.2,0.61 -0.2,0.86 1.4,-0.2 1.31,1.42 0.63,0.13 0.23,0.32 0,0 -0.47,0.57 -3.32,1.69 0.56,0.84 -0.7,0.86 -0.38,1.77 0.31,0.39 0.92,0.27 0.53,0.76 -0.22,0.87 -1.27,0.38 -2.71,1.63 -1.54,-0.19 -0.74,0.36 -1.49,1.87 -0.19,1.09 -0.86,0.24 -1.16,1.08 0.38,0.88 -0.99,0.92 -0.77,1.43 0.42,0.85 -0.5,0.52 0.53,0.53 -2.59,1.57 0.2,0.81 -0.26,0.64 -0.78,-1.33 0.03,-0.43 -0.94,-1.14 -0.87,-0.41 0.04,-0.73 -1.18,0.25 -1.93,-0.31 -0.5,0.45 -1.03,-0.4 -0.58,0.8 -0.57,0.01 -1.58,2.17 0.61,0.66 0.7,0.2 -0.52,0.44 0.46,0.77 -0.67,0.72 0.49,1.81 -1.88,1.12 -1.39,2.33 -0.63,-0.35 -0.48,0.21 -0.6,-0.17 -1.12,0.77 -2.53,0.25 0.61,0.55 -0.73,1.44 1.02,0.58 0.17,0.39 -0.66,1.1 0.09,0.83 -0.46,1.72 0.28,0.89 -0.59,1.39 -1.88,-0.39 -1.41,0.55 -0.53,0.69 -0.9,0.02 -0.85,0.82 -0.78,1.72 0.7,0.56 0.75,0.14 0.32,0.69 0.66,0.1 0.03,0.62 0.37,0.22 -1.37,0.43 -0.94,1.87 -0.57,0.31 -0.76,-0.05 -1.26,0.77 0.05,0.83 -0.74,1.28 0.17,2.6 2.44,1.43 1.28,1.87 -0.14,1 -0.52,0.29 -0.05,0.93 0.73,0.39 0.15,0.8 -0.59,0.83 -1.21,0.43 -0.34,1.75 -0.34,0.37 1.65,1.48 0.96,2.58 -0.13,1.8 0.53,2.61 -0.44,0.39 -1.34,0.15 0,0 -1.29,-0.28 -0.52,0.23 -0.52,-0.34 0,0 -0.08,-1.97 -1.13,-1.56 -0.32,-1.52 -1.12,-0.56 -1.37,-1.84 -1.42,0.11 0.02,-0.67 -0.43,-0.55 0.01,-0.92 -0.32,-0.42 -1.16,0.17 -0.75,-0.56 -1.03,0.27 -0.45,-0.57 -1.5,-0.3 -0.42,-1.05 0.42,-0.86 -0.25,-0.53 0.34,-1.02 -1.99,-0.45 -0.67,-0.93 2.15,-3.09 -0.84,-1.21 -2.35,-1.52 -0.47,-0.75 0.53,-2.37 0.78,-1.57 -0.54,-1.26 -1.5,-0.86 -0.3,-0.95 0.13,-0.89 -0.72,-2.3 -0.47,-0.49 -0.41,-2.54 0.55,-1.53 0.04,-1.33 -1.68,-2.95 -0.75,-0.46 -0.34,0.14 -1.57,-1.25 -1.1,-3.81 -0.64,-0.95 -0.39,-1.37 -1.25,-1.38 0.17,-1.45 0.33,-0.38 -1.25,-0.25 -0.96,0.88 -0.79,0.04 -0.19,-0.13 0.15,-0.48 -0.9,-0.05 -0.17,-0.61 -0.72,-0.13 -0.24,-0.41 -1.57,0.3 -0.76,-0.46 -0.44,0.14 -0.05,-0.8 -0.75,-0.02 -0.07,-2.24 -0.61,-0.42 0.35,-0.18 0.42,-1.17 -1.05,-1.57 0.02,-1.71 -0.98,-0.79 1.02,-0.29 0.27,-0.39 1.05,0.79 0.31,-0.17 -0.51,-2.42 0.17,-1.41 -1.09,-0.68 -0.31,0.19 0.12,-0.61 -0.37,-0.1 -1.05,-1.29 -0.33,-0.01 -0.89,0.77 -0.32,-0.2 -0.12,-0.68 -1.05,-0.23 -0.71,0.22 -1.07,-0.99 -1.05,-1.97 -0.82,-0.77 -0.06,-0.75 -0.4,-0.51 0.95,-1.39 -0.04,-0.41 -1.32,-1.54 -0.48,-1.11 -0.07,-1.3 -1.17,-0.38 -2.3,0.23 -0.78,0.52 -0.99,-0.5 -2.61,0.38 -0.81,-1.16 -1.1,-0.45 -0.17,-0.69 -1.63,-0.17 0,0 -0.43,0 -1.11,-0.91 -1.84,-0.11 -0.21,-1.41 -0.86,-0.58 0,0 -0.48,-1.34 -0.42,-2.96 1.07,-1.26 0.33,-0.8 -1.27,-2.99 0.05,-0.64 0.37,-0.32 -0.27,-0.9 0.07,-1.68 2.07,-1.9 0.35,-0.14 0.42,0.48 0.2,-0.62 -0.5,-0.67 -0.68,0.06 -0.66,-0.53 0.04,-1.21 1.22,-0.95 0.6,-0.85 1.28,-0.45 0.44,0.86 0.87,0.61 2.25,0.71 z"
         class="land"
         title="Alba"
         id="RO-AB" />
    <image xlink:href="ana.jpg" clip-path="url(#img)" x="0" y="0" height="50px" width="50px"/>
    </clipPath>
</g>
    </svg>
```

Why is this code now working if i save it like a html document? Please help me . I am very new in svg so do not be rude with me :)

Comment: the root element in SVG must be an <svg> element, you seem to have a <g> element.

Comment: @RobertLongson I had this between <g tranform... <svg xmlns="http:/www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 462.22 473.42">.It is not still working even with the <svg>

Comment: @RobertLongson done and thx for helping me :)

Comment: There's nothing to see, all you have is a clipPath. Did you mean to put the imahge outside the clipPath? You can't clip the image with something that's its own parent.

Comment: I want to put that image like a backgrounf on that path. I have that path and its background to be that image. It is for an interractive nap and i want the background of every city to be another picture.

Comment: You need to put the image in a pattern and apply the pattern to the path then.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks a lot ! You saved my project :))